# JAVA Splitting an array into 3 Arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I have been trying to split an array into three different arrays.

```
            Player[] arr = Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers();

        int arrl1 = (int) Math.floor(arr.length /3);
        int arrl3 = (int) Math.ceil(arr.length /3);
        int arrl2 = arr.length - (arrl3);



        Player[] arr1 = Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, 0, arrl1);
        Player[] arr2 = Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, arrl1, arrl2);
        Player[] arr3 = Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, arrl2, arrl3);

        int players = arrl1;
        Player[] Array = arr1;
```

I don't know what's going on, I keep getting all kinds of errors that are related to one array (arr1,arr2,arr3) not receiving its correct part of the player array (arr).

Say I had 5 players in array, I want to take the first 2 players and put that in array one, take the last 2 and then get the renaming third in the middle.

Help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Please, don't call a variable `Array`. If you have errors, add them to your question.

Comment: We cant help you fix "all kinds of errors"

Comment: Arrays suck. Use collections and you will notice that life gets a lot simpler

Comment: Ok, you've shown us some code and what you expected to happen. You'll need to explain what is happening more precisely that "all kinds of errors". Offhand, it looks like you're expecting the division to yield a real number, but since "arr.length" and "3" are both ints you're getting integer math. So, if arr.length is 5, you'll get arr1=1, arr2=4, arr3=1.

Answer (score 2):

Your last array copy is the problem - if you check the error message you will see why. You probably mean:

```
Player[] arr3 = Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, arrl2, arr.length);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try printing out to the console the values of length for each of the three arrays.  You are likely having overlap and/or missing an element or two.  Print out the length of these sub-arrays and see where your error is!